# Is the paper "Field Wiring and Noise Considerations for Analog Signals" talking about AC or DC signal level?

Tags: signal

The paper [Field Wiring and Noise Considerations for Analog Signals](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3344/en/) mentions the following info:

> Single-ended input connections can be used when all input signals meet
>   the following criteria:
>
> Input signals are high level (greater than 1 V)

What meant by "1V" is AC or DC here? Do they mean by 1V  a swing or offset?
In other words if the signal offset is 5V but the max swing is 100mV should I use differential ended?

Comment: Hard to say without context. Care to link to the paper?

Comment: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3344/en/

Comment: If you scroll down under Table 1. It is written there

Comment: *"Is this paper ..."* **What** paper?  You are referencing something that was not defined.

Answer (score 3):

They are referring to the amplitude of the signal, so the AC component.  Whether the signals themselves always stay positive, or have negative peaks, doesn't really matter.

The point is signal to noise ratio.  All they are saying is that you shouldn't use single-ended connections, with their inherent susceptibility to common mode noise, when the signal is less than 1 V.

This is clearly meant to be a rough guide.  For example, they are saying it would be OK to use single-ended signals for line-level audio, but not for microphone level audio, for example.

Comment: Ah. Beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

The stated reasons should be self-explanatory. **That means you must estimate or measure to find out the environment for errors in ground difference and common mode radiated noise**

> justified only if the magnitude of the induced errors is smaller than the required accuracy of the data. Single-ended input connections can be used when all input signals meet the following criteria.